# iPhone, is there any drawing sketch framework library can be use?

Tags: iphone

I want build a sketch pad app on iPhone, I assume that this type app has already been developed long time , maybe some open source code can be use for this purpose ?

anyone can give tip on this field ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Sketch example for MacOS X Cocoa, then at UIBezierPath.  Much of the drawing code should be easily portable with a regexp, although the UI and controller would need rewriting.

Comment: Hi, that is great ... but seem need add freehand way, but anyway, that is very useful...

thanks again

Comment: +1. Paul - I don't suppose you have a link to that Sketch example do you? I had a quick google but didnt seem to find it. Thanks

Comment: Should be at /Developer/Examples/Sketch; it comes with Xcode.  I can't tell if it is supplied still with the latest Xcode, but it should be.